# C++ raytracer: камера и луч

Tags: c++, linux, математика, 3d, raytracing

Всем привет,
пишу свой **raytracer** под линукс **терминал**, решил для начала описать сферу, соответственно вот её класс (использовал стандартный алгоритм для проверки пересечения вектора со сферой, в конце вопроса добавил скрин):

```
class Sphere
{
public:
    float radius;
    vector3 center;
    
    bool is_intersect(vector3 camera, vector3 ray)
    {
        // вектор от камеры до центра сферы
        vector3 v = center - camera;

        // модуль вектора
        float abs_v = v.length();

        // ray уже нормализирован ранее
        float pr_v_on_ray = ray.dot_product(v);

        float l2 = abs_v * abs_v - pr_v_on_ray * pr_v_on_ray;

        return l2 - radius * radius <= 0;
    }
};
```

vector3 - самописный тип трёхмерного вектора со всеми стандартными операциями над векторами. (модуль, скалярное произведение, нормализация и остальные)

Создаю сферу с центром в (0,0,0) и вроде бы всё работает:

```
    // от искажения, т.к. ячейки в терминале не квадратные
    float distortion = (8.0 / 16) * (width / height);

    Sphere sphere = {0.5, vector3(0,0,0)};

    for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; ++j)
        {
            vector2 xy = (vector2((float)i, (float)j) / vector2(width, height)) 
                * vector2(2,2) - vector2(1,1); // x,y Є [-1.0; 1.0]
            xy.x *= distortion;

           vector3 camera = vector3(0,0,1);
           // луч, вылетающий из камеры
           vector3 ray = vector3(xy.x, xy.y, -1).normalize();

           if (sphere.is_intersect(camera, ray)) mvaddch(j,i, '@');
```

[image: 1]

Однако, стоит изменить координаты центра сферы и происходит искажение:

```
Sphere sphere = {0.5, vector3(-0.5,-0.5,0)};
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Правильно ли я понимаю механизм "пускания" лучей из точки (камеры):
   например нам нужно пустить луч из точки (1,2,3) в точку (5,2,1), значит координаты луча будут (5-1,2-2,1-3) = (4,0,-2)? Если понятно что ray.x и ray.y должны проходить по всем пикселям терминала, то каким должно быть значение ray.z?
2. Не совсем понятно как устроены координаты камеры, я предполагаю что (x,y,z) это смещение камеры относительно начала координат, соответственно например изменяя z должнен изменяться размер проекции шара, так и есть, однако при изменении x и y всё ломается. Не понимаю как рассмотреть шар со всех 6 сторон (потом матрицы поворота привязать смогу)
3. Что вызывает искажение выше?

Моя финальная цель: камера вращающаяся вокруг сферы (источник света добавлю позже)

Алгоритм is_intersect():

[image: 222]

Comment: Так и делаю (по крайней мере считаю что так делаю), выпускаю луч ray из камеры во все точки терминала. Чего именно не хватает?

Comment: Чет я сам забыл, что хотел вчера сказать... Однако воспроизводимости примеру все-таки явно не хватает.

Comment: Вроде немного разобрался:

1) Искажения из-за FOV (подобно рыбьему глазу), соответственно исправляется изменением FOVa и отдалением камеры

2) ray.z должна быть противоположного знака в отличии от camera.z, т.е. сдвигая камеру на 0,0,3 луч мы должны пускать в обратную сторону z = -1. Но если двигать камеру не по z, а к примеру по х, то координаты луча в корне поменяются, и станут (-camera.x, xy.x, xy.y)

Пока что так, ищу и читаю все существующие статьи по тому как устроена камера в таких штуках